# Mule Object Store in a clustered environment

Tags: mule

I have a clustered Mule environment with two Mule servers on two different machines. I am using an Object Store to save and retrieve some variables. This is my Object Store configuration:-

```
<spring:beans>
    <spring:bean id="esbObjectStore" class="org.mule.util.store.SimpleMemoryObjectStore" />
</spring:beans>
<objectstore:config name="EsbObjectStore" objectStore-ref="esbObjectStore" doc:name="ObjectStore" />
```

Currently, the values that I save on one server are available only on the same server for retrieval. How do I make this object store clustered? Is there a way?

Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

You need to use custom object stores, so that you will be able to share these object stores among various mule nodes.

The ObjectStore interface has many implementations so you can choose a persistence mechanism that best suits you. Examples include Hazelcast, Redis, Ehcache, Mongo, Cassandra, JDBC. More on this here:http://java.dzone.com/articles/synchronizing-data-across-mule

Answer (score 0):

As of Mule 3.5.0, the default object store created for all new cacheing strategies supports cluster mode out of the box, with the exception of the cache scope which uses the old default cacheing strategy. For details, see the Object Stores and Clustering section in Cache Scope.

https://docs.mulesoft.com/mule-user-guide/v/3.6/cache-scope

Please confirm if this answer your question .